# Marker is not being shown in Google Maps after 2nd launch

Tags: android, kotlin, google-maps-markers

`object Constants {

```
fun buildWelcomeMessage(): String {
    return StringBuilder("Welcome, ")
        .append(currentRider!!.firstName)
        .append(" ")
        .append(currentRider!!.lastName)
        .toString()
}

fun buildName(firstName: String, lastName: String): String {
    return StringBuilder(firstName).append("").append(lastName).toString()
}

var marketList: MutableMap<String, Marker> = HashMap()
var driversFound: MutableSet<DriverGeoModel> = HashSet()
const val DRIVER_INFO_REFERENCE = "DriverInfo"
const val RIDER_INFO_REFERENCE: String = "Riders"
const val CHANNEL_ID = "myChannelRider"
const val DRIVERS_LOCATION_REFERENCES: String = "DriversLocation"
var currentRider: RiderModel? = null
const val TOKEN_REFERENCE: String = "Token"`
```

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment(), OnMapReadyCallback, FirebaseDriverInfoListener {
    private var _binding: FragmentHomeBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!
    private lateinit var mMap: GoogleMap
    private var _mapFragment: SupportMapFragment? = null

    //location
    private lateinit var locationRequest: LocationRequest
    private lateinit var locationCallback: LocationCallback
    private lateinit var fusedLocationProviderClient: FusedLocationProviderClient

    //Load driver
    private var distance = 1.0
    private val LIMIT_RANGE = 10.0
    private var previousLocation: Location? = null
    private var currentLocation: Location? = null
    private var firstTime = true
    private var cityName = ""

    //listener
    lateinit var iFirebaseDriverLocationListener: FirebaseDriverInfoListener
    lateinit var iFirebaseFailedListener: FirebaseFailedListener

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?,
    ): View {
        _binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        val root: View = binding.root
        _mapFragment = childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment
        _mapFragment!!.getMapAsync(this)

        init()
        return root
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        fusedLocationProviderClient.removeLocationUpdates(locationCallback)
        _binding = null
    }

    private fun init() {
        iFirebaseDriverLocationListener = this

        locationRequest = LocationRequest.Builder(Priority.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY, 3000).apply {
            setWaitForAccurateLocation(false)
            setMinUpdateIntervalMillis(LocationRequest.Builder.IMPLICIT_MIN_UPDATE_INTERVAL)
            setMaxUpdateDelayMillis(5000)
            setMinUpdateDistanceMeters(10f)
        }.build()

        locationCallback = object : LocationCallback() {
            override fun onLocationResult(locationResult: LocationResult) {
                super.onLocationResult(locationResult)
                //set the location on map
                val newPos = LatLng(
                    locationResult.lastLocation!!.latitude, locationResult.lastLocation!!.longitude
                )
                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(newPos, 18f))
                //if user has change location, calculate and load driver again
                if (firstTime) {
                    previousLocation = locationResult.lastLocation
                    currentLocation = locationResult.lastLocation
                    firstTime = false
                } else {
                    previousLocation = currentLocation
                    currentLocation = locationResult.lastLocation
                }
                if (previousLocation!!.distanceTo(currentLocation!!) / 1000 <= LIMIT_RANGE) {
                    loadAvailableDrivers()
                }
            }
        }
        fusedLocationProviderClient =
            LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(requireContext())
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                requireContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            fusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(
                locationRequest, locationCallback, Looper.myLooper()
            )
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                requireActivity(), arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION), 12
            )
        }
        fusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(
            locationRequest, locationCallback, Looper.myLooper()
        )
        loadAvailableDrivers()
    }

    private fun loadAvailableDrivers() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                requireContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                requireContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            Snackbar.make(
                requireView(), getString(R.string.permission_required), Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show()
            return
        }

        fusedLocationProviderClient.lastLocation.addOnFailureListener { e ->
            Snackbar.make(requireView(), e.message!!, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }.addOnSuccessListener { location ->
            if (location != null) {
                // Load all drivers in the city based on the obtained location
                val geoCoder = Geocoder(requireContext(), Locale.getDefault())
                val addressList: List<Address>?
                try {
                    @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
                    addressList =
                        geoCoder.getFromLocation(location.latitude, location.longitude, 1)
                    val cityName = addressList!![0].locality

                    //Query
                    val driverLocationRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                        .getReference(Constants.DRIVERS_LOCATION_REFERENCES).child(cityName)

                    val gf = GeoFire(driverLocationRef)
                    val geoQuery = gf.queryAtLocation(
                        GeoLocation(location.latitude, location.longitude), distance
                    )
                    geoQuery.removeAllListeners()

                    geoQuery.addGeoQueryEventListener(object : GeoQueryEventListener {
                        override fun onKeyEntered(key: String?, location: GeoLocation?) {
                            Constants.driversFound.add(DriverGeoModel(key, location))
                        }

                        override fun onKeyExited(key: String?) {
                            Constants.driversFound.remove(DriverGeoModel(key))
                        }

                        override fun onKeyMoved(key: String?, location: GeoLocation?) {
                        }

                        override fun onGeoQueryReady() {
                            if (distance <= LIMIT_RANGE) {
                                distance++
                                loadAvailableDrivers()
                            } else {
                                distance = 0.0
                                addDriverMarker()
                            }
                        }

                        override fun onGeoQueryError(error: DatabaseError?) {
                            Snackbar.make(
                                requireView(), error!!.message, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT
                            ).show()
                        }
                    })

                    driverLocationRef.addChildEventListener(object : ChildEventListener {
                        override fun onChildAdded(
                            snapshot: DataSnapshot,
                            previousChildName: String?,
                        ) {
                            //Have new Driver
                            val geoQueryModel = snapshot.getValue(GeoQueryModel::class.java)
                            val geoLocation =
                                GeoLocation(geoQueryModel!!.l!![0], geoQueryModel.l!![1])
                            val driverGeoModel = DriverGeoModel(snapshot.key, geoLocation)
                            val newDriverLocation = Location("")
                            newDriverLocation.latitude = geoLocation.latitude
                            newDriverLocation.longitude = geoLocation.longitude
                            val newDistance = location.distanceTo(newDriverLocation) / 1000 //in km
                            if (newDistance <= LIMIT_RANGE) {
                                findDriverByKey(driverGeoModel)
                            }
                        }

                        override fun onChildChanged(
                            snapshot: DataSnapshot,
                            previousChildName: String?,
                        ) {
                        }

                        override fun onChildRemoved(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                            val removedDriverKey = snapshot.key
                            Constants.driversFound.removeAll { it.key == removedDriverKey }

                            // Remove the marker from the map
                            if (Constants.marketList.containsKey(removedDriverKey)) {
                                Constants.marketList[removedDriverKey]?.remove()
                                Constants.marketList.remove(removedDriverKey)
                            }
                        }

                        override fun onChildMoved(
                            snapshot: DataSnapshot,
                            previousChildName: String?,
                        ) {
                        }

                        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                            Snackbar.make(
                                requireView(), error.message, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT
                            ).show()
                        }
                    })

                } catch (e: IOException) {
                    Snackbar.make(
                        requireView(),
                        getString(R.string.permission_required),
                        Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show()
                }
            } else {
                Snackbar.make(
                    requireView(), "Unable to retrieve location information.", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show()
            }
        }
    }

    private fun addDriverMarker() {
        Log.d("MarkerDebug", "addDriverMarker is called ")

        if (Constants.driversFound.isNotEmpty()) {
            CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
                val newDriverKeys = Constants.driversFound.map { it.key }
                val existingDriverKeys = Constants.marketList.keys

                // Remove markers for drivers that are no longer in the list
                val removedDriverKeys = existingDriverKeys.subtract(newDriverKeys.toSet())
                for (key in removedDriverKeys) {
                    Constants.marketList[key]?.remove()
                    Constants.marketList.remove(key)
                }

                // Add or update markers for new or existing drivers
                Constants.driversFound.forEach { driverGeoModel ->
                    findDriverByKey(driverGeoModel)
                    Log.d("MarkerDebug", "addDriverMarker is called when found driver: ${driverGeoModel.key}")
                }
            }
            Snackbar.make(
                requireView(), getString(R.string.drivers_are_found), Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show()
        } else {
            // No drivers found, remove all markers from the map
            for (marker in Constants.marketList.values) {
                marker.remove()
            }
            Constants.marketList.clear()
            Snackbar.make(
                requireView(), getString(R.string.drivers_are_not_found), Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show()
        }
    }


    private fun findDriverByKey(driverGeoModel: DriverGeoModel?) {
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Constants.DRIVER_INFO_REFERENCE)
            .child(driverGeoModel!!.key!!)
            .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
                override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                    iFirebaseFailedListener.onFirebaseFailed(error.message)
                }

                override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.hasChildren()) {
                        driverGeoModel.driverInfoModel =
                            (snapshot.getValue(DriverInfoModel::class.java))
                        iFirebaseDriverLocationListener.onDriverInfoLoadSuccess(driverGeoModel)
                    } else {
                        iFirebaseFailedListener.onFirebaseFailed(getString(R.string.key_not_found) + driverGeoModel.key)
                    }
                }

            })
    }

    override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap
        //enable zoom
        mMap.uiSettings.isZoomControlsEnabled = true
        //check the permission
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                requireContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                requireContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            //if we don't have permission
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                requireActivity(), arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION), 12
            )
            return
        }
        //when we have permission
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                requireContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) { //Enable button first
            mMap.isMyLocationEnabled = true
            mMap.uiSettings.isMyLocationButtonEnabled = true
            //when i click on button
            mMap.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener {
                Toast.makeText(context, "clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                //get last location
                fusedLocationProviderClient.lastLocation.addOnFailureListener {
                    Toast.makeText(context, it.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }.addOnSuccessListener { location ->
                    val userLatLng = LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude)
                    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(userLatLng, 18f))
                }
                true
            }
            val locationButton = (_mapFragment!!.requireView()
                .findViewById<View>("1".toInt()).parent!! as View).findViewById<View>("2".toInt())
            val params = locationButton.layoutParams as RelativeLayout.LayoutParams
            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, 0)
            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE)
            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_START, 0)
            params.marginStart = 15
            params.bottomMargin = 250
        }

        //try to set map style
        try {
            val success = mMap.setMapStyle(
                MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(requireContext(), R.raw.uber_maps_style)
            )
            if (!success) {
                Log.e("ErrorMap", "Map Style is not parsing")
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e("ErrorMap", e.message!!)
        }

        addDriverMarker()
    }

    override fun onDriverInfoLoadSuccess(driverGeoModel: DriverGeoModel?) {
        val driverKey = driverGeoModel?.key

        if (driverKey != null) {
            if (!Constants.marketList.containsKey(driverKey)) {
                val marker = mMap.addMarker(
                    MarkerOptions().position(
                        LatLng(
                            driverGeoModel.geoLocation!!.latitude,
                            driverGeoModel.geoLocation!!.longitude
                        )
                    ).flat(true).title(
                        Constants.buildName(
                            driverGeoModel.driverInfoModel?.firstName ?: "",
                            driverGeoModel.driverInfoModel?.lastName ?: ""
                        )
                    ).snippet(driverGeoModel.driverInfoModel?.phoneNumber ?: "")
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.car))
                )
                Log.d("MarkerDebug", "Adding marker for driver: ${driverGeoModel.key}")

                Constants.marketList[driverKey] = marker!!
            }
        }

        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(cityName)) {
            val driverLocation =
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Constants.DRIVERS_LOCATION_REFERENCES)
                    .child(cityName).child(driverKey ?: "")

            driverLocation.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
                override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                    Snackbar.make(
                        requireView(), error.message, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show()
                }

                override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                    if (!snapshot.hasChildren() && Constants.marketList.containsKey(driverKey)) {
                        // Remove the marker from the map
                        Constants.marketList[driverKey]?.remove()
                        Constants.marketList.remove(driverKey)
                        driverLocation.removeEventListener(this)
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        _mapFragment = null
    }
}
```

this one is RIDER APP here when rider opens and waits for online driver, in driver app when driver becomes online , it should show here online driver marker in google maps, when app was launched 1st time(after installation) and it worked as expected and shows on map and removed if driver offline.
when app was laucnhed 2nd time(after instalation) snack  works , says there driver found and all things but marker does not show on map

Answer (score 0):

So far I fixed like

```
private fun refreshMap() {
        // Remove all markers from the map
        for (marker in Constants.marketList.values) {
            marker.remove()
        }
        Constants.marketList.clear()
        // Reset any other marker-related objects or data as needed
        Constants.driversFound.clear()
        distance = 1.0 // Reset the distance for querying drivers
        firstTime = true // Reset the firstTime flag
        // Load available drivers again
        loadAvailableDrivers()
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        _mapFragment = null
        refreshMap()
    }
```